# Build failed with an exception in android studio

Tags: java, flutter, dart, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\richard\StudioProjects\bb\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line at the top of your build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

And then sync gradle.